# Jade - Unexpected token ILLEGAL on include

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a strange problem using JADE with server-side rendering.

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\{me}\WebstormProjects\evoliance\views\mixins\widget-container.jade:2
   1| include ./widget-container-singleton
 > 2| include ./widget-container-tilelist
   3| include ./widget-container-linelist
   4|
   5| mixin widgetContainer(display, type, data)
```

I have found that removing the include in the **widget-container-tilelist** file also remove this error :

```
include ./tilelist/links

mixin widgetContainer_tileList(type, data)
    if(type == 'links')
        +widgetContainer_tileListLinks(data)
```

But what is stranger is the fact that a similar import doesn't cause error :

```
include ./singleton/descriptors

mixin widgetContainer_singleton(type, data)
    if(type == 'descriptors')
        +widgetContainer_singletonDescriptors(data)
```

Here is the targeted include which doesn't seem to be problematic :

```
mixin widgetContainer_tileListLinks(data)
    if(data && data.length > 0)
        #component-tilelist-links
            each link in data
                a.tile-link(href=#{link.url}) #{link.title}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to interpolate a value in the href attribute of the mixin, causing an error. It should just be assigned to the property `link.url`.

```
mixin widgetContainer_tileListLinks(data)
    if(data && data.length > 0)
        #component-tilelist-links
            each link in data
                a.tile-link(href=link.url) #{link.title}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm still not at ease with the difference between the use of the *interpolation* (for string). I will be looking forward on this subject.